# Install Ocean 2014.1 SDK on VisualStudio 2013 (community edition)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, ocean, petrel

I am trying to get the ocean 2014.1 SDK appear on Visual Studio 2013 community edition. I read that I can see Ocean wizards once I install both the ocean SDK and Visual studio but I couldn't see the ocean wizards under visual C#.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Ocean 2014 is not compatible with Visual Studio 2013. And more recent Ocean installations do not show the wizards in the community edition without some extra work in Visual Studio to reference them. We support Visual Studio Standard or Professional edition as indicated by our release notes.

Comment: Thanks Keith.
I downloaded Petrel 2015 and Ocean 2015 and now everything is fine on Visual studio 2012 professional edition.